# Grabbing csv data from a website using asyncio

Tags: python, csv, asynchronous, web, python-asyncio

Recently I downloaded an IRC chat bot programmed in Python language. After playing around with the bot for a bit, I decided that I wanted to add a few custom commands that I could use. Unfortunately, Python is not my first language and I don't have the required knowledge needed to write the commands I want.

I noticed the bot code uses the asyncio and aiohttp libraries so my ocd is forcing me to write the commands using these features. So one of the commands I'm trying to write will take user input and add the input to an initial API url. This url returns a page containing csv data and looks something like this:

```
1,2277,2784439021 
15,99,152014627 
28,99,153268043 
17,99,158710483
```

How do I write a command that will read a specific integer from row 'n', col 'm' from the csv data above, using the asynchronous features? The unfinished code looks something like this:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
@commands.command()
async def lookup(self, *, user_name : str):
        user_name = user_name.split(" ")
        user_name = "+".join(user_name)
        search = "url.com/m=" + user_name
        ...
```

I couldn't find much info about scraping csv data using asyncio and aiohttp, so I'm a little lost about what the rest of the code should be. Help would be appreciated.